# Invalid exclude patterns in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Whenever I inherited a project and tried to build it with Docker (`sudo docker build -t project-name-here .`), I got the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: error from sender: invalid excludepatterns: [bin\ obj\]: syntax error in pattern
```

This is what the internals of the `.dockerignore` file are, since I'm assuming the problem stems from there:

```
bin\
obj\
```

What is the issue, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely caused by your operating system not supporting that style of slash. Try replacing the contents of the `.dockerignore` file with the following:

```
bin
obj
```

That way it will be cross-compatible across all systems.